# why does the “$d” command not work in the ex mode of vim?

Tags: vim

I found the `$d` command that can't  work in the ex mode of vim .But it can  work  in the command line mode of vim .  As follow:

I have a file called foo whose content are as follows :

```
$ cat foo
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

The follow that i tried to delete the last line of foo file  in ex mode of vim.
The last line is the line where line5 is located.

```
$ vim -E -s foo <<-EOF
> $d
> w
> EOF
```

But,the content of foo file is not change , the last line  still exists:

```
$ cat foo
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

The follow that i use the command line mode of vim  to execute `$d` command:

```
  1 line1
  2 line2
  3 line3
  4 line4
  5 line5
~
~
1          foo                                      0x6C      1,1           all
:$d
```

The result is:

```
$ cat  foo
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

The last line was successfully deleted.

In addition to using the `$d` command , i have used the `1d` command and the `1,2d` command , both commands  work properly.

**UPDATE:** add an example

The contents of foo file are as follows:

```
$ cat foo
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

I processed this file with the ex mode of vim in bash：

```
$ vim -E -s foo <<-EOF
> 1d
> 2,3d
> $d
> w
> EOF
```

The result is：

```
$ cat foo
line2
line5
```

The result I expect is that only the line where line2 is located will remain. 
But the line where line5 is located was remained , it should be deleted by `$d` command.

why ? who can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `-c`:

```
vim -c '$d' -c 'w' file
```

You used `-s {scriptin}` read man page what does it mean. You should pass a file to `-s`, and it contains: `:$d^M:w^M` (which `^M` is `ctrl-v ctrl-m`)

or:

```
vim file -s <(echo ':$d^M:w^M')
```

`^M` linebreak should be typed in the same way as above.

Comment: Does "-E"  mean the same as “-e”  to enter the ex mode? If so , does  “-s”  mean   that it enters   silent ro batch mode?

Comment: About  “-s {scriptin}”，  Does {scriptin} just able to include  the commands of normal mode ?  can it also contains   the ex commands?